# multipart file upload check mime type in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, mime-types

I am using mimeutil for checking the mimetype of a file.
And only allowing csv and json files. But getting this mimetype for a json file
"application/x-ipynb+json" mime type which is nowhere found. Any help will be appreciated to get the exact mime type of a file if also renamed a exe file to json which should not be allowed for security reasons.
Refer below code for reference:

```
public static String verifyExtension(MultipartFile File){
String mimeType = null;
        MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector");
        MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.ExtensionMimeDetector");
        //MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.OpendesktopMimeDetector");
        MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith(
              "Windows") ? "eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.WindowsRegistryMimeDetector"
              : "eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.OpendesktopMimeDetector");

        Collection<?> mimeTypes = null;
        try {
            mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(File.getBytes());
            if(mimeTypes.equals("application/vnd.ms-excel") || mimeTypes.equals("application/json") 
                    || mimeTypes.equals("application/octet-stream"))
            {
                System.out.println("File typ is csv or json");
                mimeType = "success";
            }else{
                mimeType = "fail";
            }
        } catch (MimeException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            mimeType = "fail";
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            mimeType = "fail";
        }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some examples.

Comment: u can check the code for example referring to my question. Thanks

Comment: _**@OP**_: check if the following methods help you:
 1. [`MultipartFileObject.getContentType()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getContentType--),
 2. [`MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(File file)`](http://mime-util.sourceforge.net/apidocs/eu/medsea/mimeutil/MimeUtil.html#getMimeTypes(java.io.File))

Comment: 1. this doesn't work when changed a executable file .exe to json. The mime type returned is json. 2. already using giving an unknown mimetype in response for a json file. do you know any other way to get exact mimetype of file  ?

Comment: `MediaType` is another possible partial comparison. But still, did you try to trace what exactly is fetched into variable `mimeTypes`. debug and see in `else` part of comparison. that may help.

Comment: yes mimeType gives the mimetype of file in case of csv file application/octet-stream and for upload of json sometimes its application/json or application/x-ipynb+json. Cannot figure out the later part as which mimetype it is. Anyone who has worked for secure multipart file upload by checking mimeType ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that MIME type checks in [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) are based on file extension.

In order to run actual file analysis try [Apache Tika Mime Magic Detection](http://tika.apache.org/0.7/detection.html#Mime_Magic_Detection).

Also, you can try one of the following:

1. ZIP the file before upload, then unzip on the server and test mime type
2. Upload through scalable 3rd party solution e.g. S3 bucket
3. Rename the uploaded file but send the file name in a header or URL parameter and test that for mime type

Comment: Apache Tika has many dependencies and the zip,unzip part is not feasible as the application is used make upload easy for end user for file upload from local to server directly and the file on the server is widely used.

Comment: I gave you an explanation and several possible solutions. Your objections are unjustified. It is not difficult to implement  Tika or zip/unzip a file programmatically.